RunTime of code too big, physics homework
I'm trying to do a physics homework on pyhton were I made the following code:
t1=time.time()

def F(Sa,Sb):
    if Sa > Sb:
        return Sa + np.log(1 + np.exp(Sb - Sa))
    else:
        return Sb + np.log(1 + np.exp(Sa - Sb))
        
def Stirling(n): #aproximaçao de Stirling
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n * np.log(n) - n  + 1/2 * np.log(2*np.pi*n)


spins = np.array([-2,-1,0,1,2])

def Omega(Mi,N):
    
    VStirling = np.vectorize(Stirling)
    Log_Omega_M = -np.inf*np.ones(len(Mi))
    
    for N_2minus in range(N+1):
        for N_1minus in range( N - N_2minus + 1):
            for N_0 in range(N- N_2minus - N_1minus +1):
                for N_1plus in range(N- N_2minus - N_1minus - N_0 + 1):
                    
                    N_2plus = N- N_2minus - N_1minus - N_0 - N_1plus
                    
                    N_alphas = np.array([N_2minus, N_1minus, N_0, N_1plus, N_2plus])
                    
                    M = np.sum(N_alphas*spins)
                    
                    index = np.where(Mi == M)
                    
                    s = VStirling(N)  #O numerador do quociente
                    
                    s -= np.sum(VStirling(N_alphas))
                        
                    Log_Omega_M[index] = F(Log_Omega_M[index],s)
                    
    return np.exp(Log_Omega_M)
                    
                    
N = 64
Ms = np.arange(-2*N, 2*N + 1)

Res= Omega(Ms,N)

print(np.sum(Res)/(5**N))

t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)

The code is nice, but with a large N, things start to get very slower. For N>50 is taking over than a minute, and for N=100 it takes like 10m to run. Is there a way to make my code faster? I thought about using np.meshgrid(), but don't know how.

Could you change the title and make it more specific to your question rather than a general one?

There are ways to make your code faster, but more importantly you should think more deeply about what you're trying to compute here and how that can be done in a more clever way. Your solution nests loops over N 4 deep, so has complexity O(N^4). If you think of solutions based on convolution, you can easily reduce that to a single loop with a complexity of something like O(N^2) and if you use fast Fourier transforms, you could speed that up even more, vastly reducing the slowdown for larger N. You could also precompute the Stirling values and use a lookup instead of computing them often.

Could you be more specific on the fast fourier transforms?´

You can do some basic changes to speed up the code.

Vectorize sub-functions -> Replace if-else statements with np.where to take advantage of NumPy's vectorized operations.
Avoid using np.vectorize -> It is essentially a slow for-loop.
Precompute Stirling values -> Calculate Stirling numbers outside the loop and call the values via indexing.
Optional: Python loops can be slow, but you can speed them up by using Just-In-Time (JIT) compilation with Numba.
Optional: A quadruple for-loop can often be simplified. Look for more efficient approaches to solve the problem.

